# MySQL Event query error #1064

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create an event for MySQL which should change some values when the date (Datum) is less than today. I used the CURDATE() format because that works best for me.

```
CREATE EVENT `test_event_date` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
DO BEGIN
UPDATE users
SET Subbed='Yes', Datum=''
WHERE Datum < CURDATE();
END;
```

I set it to 1 minute just for test purposes ;)

But when i try this it gives me the following error:

> **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6**

But iv'e checked it multiple times, and tried values without '' and i tried CURDATE() with '', but nothing seems to work.

Please help :c

Comment: i think you should remove `WHERE Datum < CURDATE();` semicolon at the end

Comment: You need to have a delimiter at the beginning `delimiter //` and last line as `END;//`

Comment: @The I did need it at the end

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty The DELIMETER // at the beginning did work, but i still got an error when i put // at the end. So i only did the one at teh begin and it works! Thanks (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now!

I needed the `DELIMITER //` to get it to work

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE EVENT `test_eventdate` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
DO BEGIN
UPDATE users
SET Subbed='Yes', Datum=''
WHERE Datum < CURDATE();
END;
```